# When should I release [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] object?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiapplicationdelegate, uiapplication

I'm using the following code many times in my app (especially to manage a NavigationController):

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

When should I release it ?

Thx for helping,

Stephane

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't. **Never** release your application delegate - it is managed automatically by the OS.

If you look in your app's main.m file, you'll see some code that initializes an instance of `UIApplication` that represents your app - it is its responsibility to manage the application delegate's lifecycle, not your responsibility.

**EDIT** as @Goz points out, you should `release` it if at some point you `retain` it. However, since the application object (and therefore, by extension its delegate) is guaranteed to remain in scope for the life of the app (*unless* you go messing with it), it's far better to simply **not** do any memory management on the delegate, as this avoids the possibility of accidental over-release or other related issues.

Comment: unless of course you call retain on it ... then it needs to be released.

Comment: @Goz: true, but why would you go calling retain on it? It's guaranteed to be allocated for the life of the app (unless you go an do something silly like over release it, for example...) Simply avoiding retaining/releasing at all easily prevents accidental over-release.

Comment: Nice discussion +1 for each. :)

Comment: I think I disagree. `UIApplication`, `UIAccelerometer`, and `NSFileManager` are singletons and playing with `release`/`retain` on it should not make sense if Apple implemented them in a strict way, so  `retein` returns `self` and `release` does nothing. More on singletons here http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html

Comment: Thx to you all for your thoughts!

Comment: @delirus: we're discussing `UIApplicationDelegate`, not `UIApplication`. Otherwise, you're absolutely correct.

Comment: @Mac: you're right! I've allowed myself to change question title which is misleading and points to [UIApplication sharedApplication].

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: never ever release your application delegate.

Explanation:
It often helps me how to address mem-mgmt issues, when I check how the things are declared. Take a look how `delegate` property is declared for `UIApplication`:

```
@property(nonatomic,assign) id<UIApplicationDelegate> delegate;
```

As you can see, it is **assigned property** meaning all mem-mgmt done here is just assigning pointers for an instance variable. It means calling `release` on your application delegate will result in `-dealloc` method being executed for your `MyAppDelegate`. Go and try this in debugger and you'll see that your application will receive EXC_BAD_ACCESS - i.e. it will crash.

**EDIT:** However, as Goz suggests, you can call `retain` and then `release`. But in the first place, it doesn't make sense to do this `retain/release` thing on app delegate.