# Releasing appDelegate instances?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiapplicationdelegate, uiapplication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I release [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370553/when-should-i-release-uiapplication-sharedapplication-delegate-object)

I'm creating instances of UIApplication many times in my app to access shared infos, like this:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate =  (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.ListingNav.navigationBarHidden = FALSE;
```

Well, how should it release all these appDelegate objects? Won't they create accumulated memory leaks ?

Thx for helping,

Stephane

Comment: You are not *creating* anything. You create an object by invoking a method whose name begins with "alloc", "new", "copy", or "mutableCopy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you do not call `alloc` or `retain`, then you do not need to call `release`. You do not need to release `appDelegate` in this use case.